# Spatial Autoregressive Maximum Likelihood in Julia: Multiple Parameters

Tags: julia, spatial

I have the following code that evaluates the likelihood function for a spatial autoregressive model in Julia, like so:

```
function like_sar2(betas,rho,sige,y,x,W)
n = length(y)
A = speye(n) - rho*W
e = y-x*betas-rho*sparse(W)*y
epe = e'*e
tmp2 = 1/(2*sige)
llike = -(n/2)*log(pi) - (n/2)*log(sige) + log(det(A)) - tmp2*epe
end
```

I am trying to maximize this function but I'm not sure how to pass the different sized function inputs so that the Optim.jl package will accept it. I have tried the following:

```
optimize(like_sar2,[betas;rho;sige;y;x;W],BFGS())
```

and

```
optimize(like_sar2,tuple(betas,rho,sige,y,x,W),BFGS())
```

In the first case, the matrix in brackets does not conform due to dimension mismatch and in the second, the Optim package doesn't allow tuples.

I'd like to try and maximize this likelihood function so that it can return the numerical Hessian matrix (using the Optim options) so that I can compute t-statistics for the parameters.

If there is any easier way to obtain the numerical Hessian for such a function I'd use that but it appears that packages like FowardDiff only accept single inputs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I correctly understand how your function works, but it seems to me like you're using the likelihood to estimate the coefficient vector beta, with the other input variables fixed. The way to do this would be to amend the function as follows:

```
using Optim

# Initialize some parameters
coeffs = rand(10)
rho = 0.1
ys = rand(10)
xs = rand(10,10)
Wmat = rand(10,10)
sige=0.5

# Construct likelihood with parameters fixed at pre-defined values
function like_sar2(β::Vector{Float64},ρ=rho,σε=sige,y=ys,x=xs,W=Wmat)
  n = length(y)
  A = speye(n) - ρ*W
  ε = y-x*β-ρ*sparse(W)*y 
  epe = ε'*ε
  tmp2 = 1/(2*σε)
  llike = -(n/2)*log(π) - (n/2)*log(σε) + log(det(A)) - tmp2*epe
end

# Optimize, with starting value zero for all beta coefficients
optimize(like_sar2, zeros(10), NelderMead())
```

If you need to optimize more than your beta parameters (in the general autoregressive models I've used often the autocorrelation parameter was estimated jointly with other coefficients), you could do this by chugging it in with the beta vector and unpacking within the functions like so:

```
append!(coeffs,rho)

function like_sar3(coeffs::Vector{Float64},σε=sige,y=ys,x=xs,W=Wmat)
  β = coeffs[1:10]; ρ = coeffs[11]
  n = length(y)
  A = speye(n) - ρ*W
  ε = y-x*β-ρ*sparse(W)*y 
  epe = ε'*ε
  tmp2 = 1/(2*σε)
  llike = -(n/2)*log(π) - (n/2)*log(σε) + log(det(A)) - tmp2*epe
end
```

The key is that you end up with one vector of inputs to pass into your function.